Maximum Execution Time Question "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"
I'm interested in getting more insight into how the maximum execution time in PHP/Laravel works. I tried to Google it myself, but wasn't successful. Here is the problem:
I wrote a piece of code in Laravel that gets data from a API, extract wanted data from the response and then saves it to the database. Essentially a product importer.)
At first I had the whole code in a single function and everything seemed to be working fine. The whole import ran for about 45 minutes (due to the API request limitations). I never once got a "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" fatal error.
Then once I got everything working I decided to start refactoring my code and make it into little separate functions. The importer logic stayed the same and nothing was added just moved to separate functions. Once I had done that and ran the importer again voila I got the good old "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" error. Which is quite baffling to me because the nature of the importer stayed the same it was just split up into smaller understandable functions.
Furthermore, I could not understand what was causing the issue, so I thought I'd try my luck here. My aim isn't to fix the issue, because I can do that just by set_time_limit(n); at the start of each loop.
I am more interested in what could have caused the issue and how exactly does the maximum execution time work and behave. I would be very thankful to any documentation or explanation.
Thank you in advance.
P.S I would put both of the code snippets here, but I wasn't using version control at that time (silly me)
public function importItems(): void
    {
        $totalRequests = 1;
        $totalItems = 0;
        $start = 0;
        $errorCount = 0;

        Log::info('IMPORTER: Started');
        $apiConnector = new APIConnector();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRequests; $i++) {
            $requestStartTime = microtime(true);
            $response = $apiConnector->getData('1', $start, 100, $this->Id, 'price', 'asc');

            if (!$this->responseValidation($response)) {
                if ($errorCount >= 3) {
                    continue;
                }
                $errorCount++;
                $i--;
                continue;
            } else {
                $errorCount = 0;
            }

            $response = $response->json();
            $start = $response['start'] + $response['pagesize'];

            if ($i == 1) {
                $totalItems = $response['total_count'];
                $totalRequests = $this->calculateTotalRequests($totalItems);
            }

            $this->saveItemsToDatabase($this->extractItemsData($response['results']));
            Log::info('IMPORTER: ' . $start . '/' . $totalItems . ' imported');
            //Needs to sleep due to request limit
            usleep(12000000 - ((microtime(true) - $requestStartTime) * 1000000) + 1000000);

            //usleep($this->calculateSleepTime($this->calculateRequestTime($requestStartTime, microtime(true))));
        }
        Log::info('IMPORTER: Complete');
    }

I tryed using a Log to determin when and where in the code the error happens. It happens during the sleep time between each request which is about 12 seconds and it happens on the 5th loop, which makes sense as one loop takes just a little over 12 seconds.

The timeout almost certainly has nothing to do with your refactoring. This sort of long-running process is best done from the command line and not from the web via php-fpm. Then your execution time doesn't really matter that much.

Side note -- check out the response from the API, if there's a rate limit, there's usually a header (like Retry-After) that will give you a timestamp when you can try next. Where present, you can use that for your timer so that you don't have to blindly sleep a set amount.

Alex Howansky, the API doesn have a request limit, but I'm handeling that. I'm doing that in 2 ways. First, the 12 second loop time which consist of about 11.2 seconds of sleep time, is to esentially never to run into the request limit, because then it would have a 4/5 minute cooldown. Second way, is when I go over the limit (which shouldn't happen) I'm catching it and sleeping for 5min to wait out the cooldown and then try again.

You're misunderstanding. What I'm saying is that it's possible that you might be able to make your loop significantly faster by using the header information in the response to not wait at all until you need absolutely need to, and then, only wait for the absolute minimum time required. (This all depends on what the API gives you. I've seen APIs that only give you a 419 with no further details or timestamps, so it's a crap shoot.) This isn't directly related to your timeout issue, just a possible tip.

Getting a 60 sec execution limit error means your execution time limit is 60 secs. How on earth did you get your script to run for 45 minutes previously without running into that error? Are you sure this refactoring is all that changed? Any chance you can provide a "diff" of your code e.g. a before and after?

The most important comment from @AlexHowansky is that you should never run a process that takes this long from php-fpm. This should run in the background. These limits are there for a reason.
